# Angular2, State of UI/Template being cached between route changes

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have been building an app on Angular2.beta.0, I have implemented the router and the components.

I have an overlay and a simple modal based menu on one of the component template, clicking on a link in the menu would change the route and load an another relevant component.

If, by using the back button of the browser, the previous component with the modal is accessed, The modal and the overlay maintains their open state.

These modals reside in the component template itself and are initially set to display none and are showed/hidden using jQuery on a button click.

This does not seem to be a template caching issue since if the template were being cached, the modals would be hidden, rather the state of the DOM with the template is being cached.

Comment: Add `provide(APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY, {useValue : 0})` in your bootstrap.

Comment: @Eric Martinez, It works, but if you could elaborate it more.

Comment: As you correctly guessed the DOM is being cached, this is by default. Read this [comment by @tbosch](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4795#issuecomment-151688714)

Comment: Ok, You could post an answer and I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @codin

By default Angular2 caches the DOM and reuses it (check [@tbosch's comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4795#issuecomment-151688714)). To prevent this behavior you can use [`APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view_pool.ts#L8) and giving it `0` as value.

```js
bootstrap(MyApp, provide(APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY, {useValue : 0}));
```